# How to transform the digits of a number?

Tags: c

If the input is an integer [**not array**]: **6977**. I need to change every 9 to 7 so the result will be: **6777**.

This is the code that I write this is an idea that I was thinking how could I solve the problem but it's so wrong. The whole point of my homework is to change the specific number[element] of the number and I don't know how to do that. The function should do that. more examples: input: 12345555 [change every 5 into 3] result should be 12343333.

```
int function (int *n,int i){
    int temp=n[i]; //tepmorary veraible of the passed number
    int result=10;
    int devided;
    while (temp!=0){
        devided=temp%10;//get the last number example 123 = 3;
        if (devided==9){ //if its 9 change the last didigt to 7
            devided=7;
        }
        result*=devided;//multiply the last didgit with 10
        temp/=10;
    }

    return result;
}

void main (void){
    int a[100],i=0;
    while (scanf_s ("%d",&a[i])){
        printf ("%d",function(a,i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You should also explain what is wrong in detail.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Please post whatever code you have. I'll give you a hint, though. Use a looping construct with integer division and modulus to go through each digit. The solution should become apparent.

Comment: Your removing the code has made this question worse. Did you take the site tour? You also haven't specified any constraints on the integer, e.g. what is the minimum and maximum possible value? Is it always a matter of changing 9 to 7?

Comment: @pzaenger it's okay if I don't put any code?

Comment: I will put better code thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Still not an MCVE. Where's your `main` function?

Comment: You never put `devided` into the result.

Comment: Despite regular edits (thank you - close vote retracted) you haven't told us what the constraints on the number are.

Comment: I tried my best to explain what the program should do. I don't know what to add anymore!

Comment: The constraints on the number may not matter (although always positive and smaller than the biggest int would help). Even if the number arrives as an integer, you can convert it using itoa() and then process it as a string then use atoi to convert back. Or, you could process it as an integer in a while loop using a divider that is multiplied by 10 on every iteration (thus extracting the decimal place values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic of `result*=devided;` is wrong. You need to add the digit(multiplied by it's 10's place) to the result. Here is the solution to your problem.

```
int function (int *n, int i){
    int temp=n[i]; //tepmorary veraible of the passed number
    int result=0;
    int mult=1;
    int devided;
    while (temp!=0){
        devided=temp%10;//get the last number example 123 = 3;
        if (devided==9){ //if its 9 change the last didigt to 7
            devided=7;
        }
        result+=(devided * mult);//multiply the last didgit with 10
        temp/=10;
        mult*=10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note: `mult*=10` will overflow when `n[i]` is large.  I doubt this undefined behavior will cause too much trouble here though.

Comment: @chux `n[i]` is an integer and the while loop runs accordingly. So, how can `mult` overflow?

Comment: Try `n[I]==INT_MAX`.  What is the final value of `mult`?